# '..' has private access in

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with my code. I can't resolve a problem with this :( I send screen[image]:

Comment: In `Questions_Driving_licenece` class, the member `questions` is declared `private` and you can't access it. Make it `public`.

Comment: You should be able to access those variables by setting up Getters and Setters.

Comment: This question would be more useful if you shared the relevant parts of your source code as text.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access variables which are set private.
Use getter to get the variables and then perform operations on it. Use

`public String getQuestions(){
        return questions;
    }`

in the `Questions_Driving_License` class.

Answer (score 0):

Create public getter for those fields in `Questions_Driving_license` class e.g.:

```
public String questions(){
  return this.questions;
}
```

And then use this getter like this:

```
questions_Driving_license.getQuestions().length
```

What is more the class should be named `QuestionsDrivingLicence`.

Comment: `Don't make it public. Create public getter` - Typo?